# Issue clicking Javascript button with python/Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to click the button labled "Pickup" at the following link :

https://firehouse.alohaorderonline.com/StartOrder.aspx?SelectMenuType=Retail&SelectMenu=1000560&SelectSite=01291

My code is below but does nothing until it fails with the error

> element not interactable

```
pickupurl = 'https://firehouse.alohaorderonline.com/StartOrder.aspx?SelectMenuType=Retail&SelectMenu=1000560&SelectSite=1291'

driver = webdriver.Chrome('d:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.implicitly_wait(80)
driver.get(pickupurl)



button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_PickupButton"]')
button.click()
```

The code appears to locate an element as when I print 'button' I get an element object.

I've tried using driver.execute_script to execute the onclick= attribute but this does nothing as well.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You asked if you had the wrong element... you were doing want the `onClick` of the JS would have done... but the main issue I think is, you are using `find_elements_by_xpath` you should use `find_element_by_xpath` without the "S"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works for me

```
from selenium import webdriver

d = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://firehouse.alohaorderonline.com/StartOrder.aspx?SelectMenuType=Retail&SelectMenu=1000560&SelectSite=01291'
d.get(url)
d.execute_script('document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl00_Content_Content_btnPickup").click();')
```

---

Helpful warning from @Andersson

*element.click() executed via execute_script doesn't really makes a click, but just triggers onclick action of element (link, input, button, etc). So if you're using this approach for web-testing you might miss tons of bugs*

Comment: this works too! I do think it is better to use the `find_element` methods of `webdriver` rather than `execute_script` correct me if I'm wrong...

Comment: Thanks that did it. Was I simply not locating the right element?

Comment: And again you should warn OP about possible drawbacks of using `execute_script` to click element. If OP is engaged in web-application testing - this approach should not be used!

Comment: @Andersson I am a python newbie so appreciate any advice and more info on that warning.

Comment: It's actually not related to Python, but to JS. `element.click()` executed via `execute_script` doesn't really *makes a click*, but just triggers `onclick` action of element (link, input, button, etc). So if you're using this approach for web-testing you might miss tons of bugs...

Comment: @MosheSlavin's answer should be accepted instead of this one,

Answer (score 4):

Using [`WebDriverWait`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) and [`expected_conditions`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html) is a good practice!

see [explicit-waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits).

This works for me:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

pickupurl = 'https://firehouse.alohaorderonline.com/StartOrder.aspx?SelectMenuType=Retail&SelectMenu=1000560&SelectSite=1291'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('d:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(pickupurl)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
pickup_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='btnPickupDiv']/div[@class='Button']")))

pickup_button.click()
loacter = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "AddressZipLabelDiv")))
driver.quit()
```

The issue you had probably had something to do with `find_elements_by_xpath` you should use `find_element_by_xpath` without the `s`...